# You uploaded an Android App Bundle without 'android:exported' property set

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've built and Android App Bundle via Unity using target API level as 32. When I try to upload the .aab file to Google Play, I'm getting this error message:

> "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher."

I can successfully upload .aab files I've created with API level 30, but I want to fully support Android 12 devices. When I try to build with API level 31 or 32, I get this error. I've already added `android-exported` tag to all activities, and I'm not sure why I keep getting this error. Minimum API Level is set to 21 (setting it to 23 also didn't work).

I'm using Unity 2020.3.30 (also was getting same error when building with Unity 2019.4.12). Also tried to export project and build .aab via Android Studio 4.4.1, but still no luck.

My Android.Manifest file is set as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.unity3d.player" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon">
    <!-- The MessagingUnityPlayerActivity is a class that extends
         UnityPlayerActivity to work around a known issue when receiving
         notification data payloads in the background. -->
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:exported="true" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density" android:resizeableActivity="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:exported="false" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:exported="false" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityGamingServicesFriendFinderActivity" android:exported="false" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityAppLinkActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityGameRequestActivity" android:exported="false"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityCreateGameGroupActivity" android:exported="false"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityJoinGameGroupActivity" android:exported="false"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="xxxx" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoLogAppEventsEnabled" android:value="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled" android:value="true" />
    <provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderxxxx" android:exported="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.allow-resizable-window" android:value="False" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="xxxx" />
    <receiver android:name="com.unity.androidnotifications.UnityNotificationManager" android:exported="true" />
    <receiver android:name="com.unity.androidnotifications.UnityNotificationRestartOnBootReceiver" android:enabled="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vulkan.version" android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

I've tried methods from answers and comments at other similar questions in StackOverflow, but none of them worked.

Comment: Try to add exported to `<receiver android:name="com.unity.androidnotifications.UnityNotificationRestartOnBootReceiver" android:enabled="false">` your receiver also, since it has intent filters